# Получение headers в ImapX

Tags: c#

Кто подскажет, как получить headers в ImapX с высокой скоростью? Это нужно для обработки порядка 9000 писем. Которые нужно отфильтровать по e-mail и subject.

Использую данную функцию:

```
public void GetMessages(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
        {
            ImapClient client = new ImapClient();

            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

            client.Login(username, password);

            client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Headers;

            var msg = client.Folders.Inbox.Messages;

            client.Folders.Inbox.Messages.Download("ALL", ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Minimal);



    }
```

Функция работает в отдельном потоке. Происходит выход из функции во время Download. При этом ошибок никаких не выводится.

Comment: >вываливается на Download - как вываливается то без ошибок?

Comment: Просто завершается поток и все. Видимо там используется неуправляемый код